# MySQL - Is it possible to assign permission to count the number of tables in a database without permissions on individual tables?

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5, permissions

As part of a script I am trying to count the number of tables that exist in a particular MySql schema.

Using my own user I am using the query

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM information_schema.tables
WHERE table_schema = dbName
```

However I'd like the user running this script to have as few permissions as possible, specifically I don't want them to have any select privileges on any of the tables belonging to the schema

Is it possible to assign a grant which would allow a user to count the number of tables without having any access to the tables themselves?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

afaik, this is not possible. However, as an workaround you can create function which makes count(*) under required schema and grant execute on this function to user. User will not be able to access table, but will get required count.

Comment: I came to the same conclusion that it wasn't possible looking at the permissions available, but a stored procedure is a good workround, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

One option would be to give the user access to a single non-`NULL` column that doesn't provide very much information, but will allow `COUNT(*)` to succeed.

For example:

`GRANT SELECT(TABLE_TYPE) ON INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES TO blind_user@localhost;`

Now, `blind_user@localhost` can execute `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES` but can't get any private data out of the table itself.